# Why Axios GET request sending twice in Node Express?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I wrote a very simple Express app that uses Axios to GET data from an API.

I tested with Google Chrome and was able to get API data successfully. But checking the console log, it seems that the GET request from Axios was ran 2 times. 1 time success, 1 time fail.

I am not sure if this is working as intended or am I doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Code below

```js
const app = express()

app.get('/:id' , (req, res)=>{

    const fullURL = url + req.params.id
    
    axios.get( fullURL , {
        params: {
            apikey: apikey,
            limit: 10
        }
    }).then((response)=>{
        console.log('Success')
        res.send(response.data)
        
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log('Error')
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`App is running on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

Below is my console log result

Success
Error

Comment: I think .then happens regardless of whether the request succeeds or fails. This means that the request only happened once, but failed.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, are you sure you haven't sent 2 requests?

Comment: It is possible that "res.send(response.data)" produces an error that the .catch then catches. Have you tried commenting out that line?

Comment: it would be helpful to log the actual error in .catch (or at least error.message). That might give more insight on what is going on.

Comment: Base on suggestion, I just tested with POSTMAN as well and only 1 request comes up. I am guessing testing with Google Chrome is what caused the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and print the id in the request.
I believe it is the */favicon.ico* request that is sent by the browser which is being taken as the id in your api.
So, the first request is a proper one with the correct id and it gives you success response. the next request is the favicon.ico request that gets you an error from axios!
Cause I observed the same using browser and postman.
From browser -> I get 2 requests,
From postman -> I get 1 request

Comment: I tested POSTMAN as per your suggestion. And it correctly comes back as 1 result only. So I guess browser somehow was calling the REST API twice for unknown reason, but as long as its not my code being wrong, I am totally ok with that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to print the error object you receive within the catch block.
My guess is that you get into the then block, prints 'success', then you probably getting an exception in the send function, and then you reach the catch block and prints 'error'.